# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'utils' when importing indirectly from a sub package

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, python-import

I have the folder structure below:

[image]

further down, in the same package as `account_test.py` I have `utils.py` that is imported in `account_test.py` using the following command:

```
from utils import account_tester
```

This works fine when I call the `account_test` directly. However, when I try to import `account_test` into `new_account_test.py` using the following command:

```
from .. import account_test
```

I get the error below:

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'utils'`

I know there are several similar issues on this but I haven't found something matching exactly and it must be related to me importing using a relative path but can't figure out the correct syntax.

Comment: So I resolved the issue with using "from tests.utils import account_tester" in account_test.py, which gives me an idea of what was going on but would appreciate an explanation from an expert.